# How to exclude a directory tree on 'git fetch'

Tags: git

Can I exclude a directory tree on fetch?

That is, my project looks like this

```
.../project/
    .../.git/
    .../common_stuff/
    .../stuff_team_1_cares_about/
    .../stuff_team_2_cares_about/
```

The project integrator wants to do "git fetch" and get everything, but the guys on team_1 one want to do "git fetch" and NOT get changes to the stuff team_2 is working on, and vice versa.

I tried .git/info/exclude, but either I specified the exclusion wrong, or it is intended for another purpose. ( I used lines of the form "stuff_team_2_cares_about/*")

I could create three separate repositories, and have each team clone two of the three, but it would be cleaner (IMHO) to store everything in a common repo for customer delivery. Is there a textbook answer to this situation?

Answer (score 1):

To use separate repositories but still make it easy for teams to keep in-sync with each other, you can make `stuff_team_1_cares_about` and `stuff_team_2_cares_about` [submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules) of the repository.